# Need help placing my data into a multiple regression equation

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pspp

I was asked to provide a multiple regression equation on top of the reported results on my paper. I am looking at several guides and tutorials as to how to calculate one but I am very confused.

One of the sources I'm looking at show the formula as: y = mx1 + mx2+ mx3+ b

but I'm really not sure how to put this data into place. Guide's examples show b as 0 but I cannot find which value that's supposed to be on my PSPP output. Also one of the sources show "m" to be a changing value whereas the other source uses "m" as the intercept value that's stable (which I think I don't have on my data)

TLDR: I'm extremely confused trying to make sense of my data since tutorials either use SPSS or Excel and I'm trying to figure it out on PSPP. Could someone please help me make sense of this in creating a multiple regression equation?

My data: https://i.imgur.com/VasiB3e.jpg

Answer (score 1):

your b is 3.64   (value of y when all 4 of your predictors have zero value )

you have 4 m's   4 predictors  one for each of your 4 predictors and 1 y dependent

m1= -2.08
m2=   .34
m3=   .15
m4= - .04

your equation is y=  3.64 -2.08*m1 + .34 *m2  +.15*m3 -.04*m4

i corrected the above .

What do you mean x in the mx1 ? I am confused by that

Comment: Thank you for the information. Does this mean that I can fill the equation as: y=.20-.34-.15+04 or do I need to do something for the "x" in the "mx1"?

Comment: I understand it much better now. I was confused thinking it actually needed a solution. Thank you for your answers, very helpful.